# delphi xe2 tms components unavailable under x64 platform

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Instaled tms components 6.1.4.1 in delphi xe2.
Under x32 platform they work ok but under x64 platform
they are unavailable. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Are you using a Firemonkey application by mistake?   As they won't show up there.    Only in a VCL application.     You need to Add the Target Platform for the project yourself for 64bit.

Comment: No,this is VCL application. When I add target platform (x64) I cant use even one of the components.

Comment: Did they claim to support 64 bit? Did you contact tms support?

Comment: I tried it here. If I was in 64-bit mode, the palette entries are grey.  If I start as 32 and then switch, everything looks good until I compile, then it can't find the DCUs for the components that it added to the "uses" clause.  Oh well.

Comment: Yes Chris, that's exactly what I am going through ...

Comment: That's the kind of questions one should ask the vendor. If he's a customer, of course...

Comment: True indeed: Products, support information & special benefits are only for [registred customers](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/regsearch_input.asp) :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think TMS released these components too soon without proper testing.
First,the trick to manually supply sources path to x64 platform does not work
(should I say that it is utterly stupid that the installer did not do this by itself).
Now Embarcadero is supplying service packs too (not even a month from the release),
while TMS is catching up (if?).
I think devexpress and Raize are wise to keep testing the components before they label them
'ready for xe2'.

Answer (score 5):

After some exchange with TMS Software it seems that the problem come with the changes of different platform implementation with components.
So the solution it's as you said in the previous comment. Stay in 32 bits and put the components and the code. And only at the end compile in 64 Bits.
For the error of the compiler go to Tools Menu, Options, Delphi Options, Library. Select 32 Bits, Copy the path that you have for the TMS Components. And select after 64 Bits, and paste the Path that you have copied from the 32 Bits.
Compile and it works.

Comment: It's usual to edit your answer rather than to post a second answer. Or to delete the one you no longer find useful rather than to post two answers to the same question.

Comment: Ok sorry, I'm not here since a long time

Comment: Thierry,you put me on the right track.However,adding components path is not enough (it will not work).You must add C:\Program Files(x86)\Embarcadero\Rad Studio\9.0\lib\win64\release to library path for 64 platform in order to work. Now,everything works OK. Thank you all !

Comment: I spoke too soon .... It seems only some components will compile under x64 platform,others will not.Like advgrid. StringGrid however,works without a problem. Crap !

Answer (score 2):

If we look at the TMSSoftware Website it seems that it's the **v6.1.5.0** of the TMS Components Pack which is ready for the Delphi XE2.

On this page :

http://tmssoftware.com/site/

The message of the first of September. Title : "Info: TMS Component Pack v6.1.5.0 ready for Delphi XE2 & C++Builder XE2"